# How would I render a dynamic definition list using AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs

How would I render a dynamic definition list using AngularJS?

Example:

Data:

```
[
    {
        key: 'a',
        value: 'x'
    }, {
        key: 'b',
        value: 'y'
    }
]
```

Desired HTML:

```
<dl>
    <dt>a</dt>
    <dd>x</dd>
    <dt>b</dt>
    <dd>y</dd>
</dl>
```

The example at http://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_08:

```
<dl>
    <dt>Availability</dt>
    <dd ng-repeat="availability in phone.availability">{{availability}}</dd>
</dl>
```

works for a dynamic number of dds and a static number of dts, but not a dynamic number of both.

Answer (score 103, accepted):

A new feature which allows ng-repeat-start/ng-repeat-end was added in Angular 1.2.

With this feature, you can write your html like this:

```
<dl>
  <dt ng-repeat-start="i in items">{{i.key}}</dt>
  <dd ng-repeat-end>{{i.value}}</dd>
</dl>
```

See [this plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/9BhyYhQlQMRZtZKIsZ8G?p=preview) for a full working example.

Comment: Have you tried to use this feature ? I got the error: `TypeError: Object #<Text> has no method 'hasAttribute'`

Comment: @gevgeny there seems to be a bug where you cannot have any text (including whitespace) between ng-repeat-start and ng-repeat-end. This plunker works: http://plnkr.co/edit/9BhyYhQlQMRZtZKIsZ8G

Comment: @gevgeny I've made a pull request for this issue now: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/pull/2859

Answer (score 9):

I've created a directive called [repeatInside](https://github.com/bigblind/angular-repeat-inside) to solve problems like this one.

```
<dl repeat-inside="word in dictionary">
    <dt>{{word.name}}</dt>
    <dd>{{word.definition}}</dd>
</dl>
```

Comment: Nice and simple, I liked this better than the suggested official "start"/"end" directives.

Comment: Works great in angular < 1.2

Comment: I haven't worked on this for ages, I'll take a look this afternoon (GMT+1)

Comment: The code now works with the latest version of angular, and I've only had to update the example to use myApp.controller to define the controller. If you have a use case that does not yet work, please let me know.

Answer (score 7):

This is a problem, because you need to wrap it with some element in order to do repeating. And that's not gonna be a valid html - you would get into the same trouble with unordered lists or tables...

```
<dl>
  <div ng-repeat="i in items">
    <dt>{{i.key}}</dt>
    <dd>{{i.value}}</dd>
  </div>
</dl>
```

I guess the `div` inside `dl` is not allowed by spec, but it works - at least in Chrome :-D

We plan to support `ng-repeat` inside a comment to support this.

Comment: I'm accepting your answer not because your workaround actually works (see e.g. http://jsfiddle.net/JyWdT, which doesn't fully work at least in Chrome (all elements should be colored)), but because you are an Angular developer who says it is impossible, and I therefore will assume it is impossible.

Comment: The problem is, that html does not allow you to wrap these elements - there is no allowed element for that. That's why our compiler already supports directives in comments, so that we can allow ng-repeat defined in a comment in the future...

Comment: I hit this same issue while trying to render out three `span`s per collection item, without wrapping them in a parent. It doesn't seem that this has been addressed. Any update on this, or perhaps a different workaround?

Comment: or like spry before you you could have a directive called ng-repeat-children which does not use the element in which the directive was defined but only its children.

Comment: @DrewNoakes Maybe the answer at http://stackoverflow.com/a/16808545/699700 would work for you, if you put `ng-repeat-start` on the first span and `ng-repeat-end` on the third span.

Answer (score 3):

This answer didn't seem to work for me in Angular v1.2.7 so I wanted to post a slight variation that worked well for me:

```
<dl>
    <dt ng-repeat-start="(key, value) in items">{{key}}</dt>
    <dd ng-repeat-end>{{value}}</dd>
</dl>
```