# What's the difference between $evalAsync and $timeout in AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-timeout

I've been using AngularJS for a little while now, and have found the need to use [$timeout](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$timeout) every once in a while (Seems to usually be to init a jQuery plugin).

Recently, I've been trying to get a better and more in-depth understanding of the digest cycle, and I came across [$evalAsync](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$rootScope.Scope#$evalAsync) function.

It seems like that function produces similar results to `$timeout`, only you don't give it delay. Every time I've used `$timeout` it has been with a delay of 0, so now I'm wondering if I should have used `$evalAsync` instead.

Are there any fundamental differences between the two? What cases would you use one over the other? I'd like to get a better feeling of when to use which one.

Answer (score 269, accepted):

I recently answered essentially this question here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17239084/215945
(That answer links to some github exchanges with Misko.)

To summarize:

- if code is queued using **$evalAsync from a directive**, it should run *after* the DOM has been manipulated by Angular, but *before* the browser renders
- if code is queued using **$evalAsync from a controller**, it should run *before* the DOM has been manipulated by Angular (and before the browser renders) -- rarely do you want this
- if code is queued using **$timeout**, it should run *after* the DOM has been manipulated by Angular, and *after* the browser renders (which may cause flicker in some cases)

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. One thing I'm not sure I understand though. Why does it make a difference if you're calling $evalAsync from a controller or a directive? The asyncQueue doesn't know whether it was registered from a controller or a directive, it just queues it up on the current scope. Does it have to do with when stuff runs in a controller vs a controller? I just want to understand that part.

Comment: @dnc253, I haven't looked at the Angular code, so I don't know the answer to your (good) question.  Hopefully someone else can comment.

Comment: does "from a directive" mean "from the linking function of a directive"? Or is that true of the behavior when executed from either the link or controller method of a directive?

Comment: yep, it's really unclear what "from a directive" and "from a controller" mean here

Comment: @MarkRajcok, can you please clarify here: _if code is queued using $evalAsync from a directive, it should run after the DOM has been manipulated by Angular_ - should it run after the DOM has been manipulated by this directive, or by other directives?

Comment: Great answer! Is this explicitly stated somewhere in the documentation (my problem was solved by using $timeout(0) so I'm particularly interested in that)? The closest I found is https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/scope, but not really as explicit as I'd like :-)

Answer (score 61):

For those building complex applications, be aware that there is a performance impact on your choice. Also, I would like to complete Mark answer with more technical details:

- **$timeout(callback)** will wait for the current digest cycle to be done (i.e. angular update all model and the DOM), then it will execute its callback - potentially affecting angular model - then launch a full `$apply` on the root $scope, and redigest everything.
- **$evalAsync(callback)**, on the other hand, will add the callback to the current, or next, digest cycle. Which means if you are within a digest cycle (for instance in a function called from some `ng-click` directive), this will not wait for anything, the code will be executed right away. If you are within an asynchronous call, for instance a `setTimeout`, a new digest cycle (`$apply`) will be triggered.

So in terms of performances it is always better to call `$evalAsync`, unless it is important for you that the view is up to date before executing your code, for instance if you need acces to some DOm attribute such as elements width and the like.

If you want more details about the distinction between $timeout, $evalAsync, $digest, $apply, I invite you to read my answer on that other question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/23102223/1501926

Also be sure to read the [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$evalAsync):

> The $evalAsync makes no guarantees as to when the expression will be executed, only that:
>
> - it will execute after the function that scheduled the evaluation (preferably before DOM rendering).
> - at least one $digest cycle will be performed after expression execution.
>
> Note: **if this function is called outside of a $digest cycle, a new $digest cycle will be scheduled**. However, it is encouraged to always call code that changes the model from within an $apply call. That includes code evaluated via $evalAsync.

Comment: Can you please explain why $timeout is needed if I need to access some DOM attribute. Let's say if I have <table width="{{x}}">  Doesn't ng-bind's watch function update the dom attribute in the memory, I understand it will not have a chance to repaint the view until digest cycle exits.

Comment: @SridharChidurala because the DOM (the "HTML") is updated during the digest cycle, you have have to wait for it to be done before you can read the mofifications. However this is discouraged by Angular, you should read `x` from your scope directly rather than from the DOM, so you don't have to wait for anything. Also, you should better use `ng-style` with css rather than the obsolete `width` property. If you need more help, please open a new question on StackOverflow.