# AngularJS: Is there a way to know when directives contained inside another directive have loaded?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have a directive that contains a list of other directives. In each of these sub-directives, they could have any number of `.item` HTML elements. Inside of the parent directive, I would like to reference all of these `.item` elements using jQuery. So I have tried the following:

**HTML Structure**

```
<parent>
  <div class='item'></div>
  <ul>
    <li ng-repeat='child in children'>
       <!-- loads template that may have one or more divs with .item on them -->
       <child='child' /> 
    </li>
  </ul>
</parent>
```

and Inside of the parent `link()` function I call `$(".item").size()`. In this case, it always returns 1. Is there a way to call a function once all of the child directives have been loaded so I can access all of the internal .item elements?

Answer (score 0):

I guess, it's because you query DOM too soon, before inner directives run.
Try:

```
setTimeout(function(){
   $(".item").size();
}, 0);
```

or `$timeout` if you need to do something related with scope in timeout callback function.

You could also try:

```
scope.$evalAsync(function(){
  $(".item").size();
});
```

but it's hard to tell which one will work without code sample.
You can read more about `setTimeout` and `$evalAsync` differences here: [AngularJS : $evalAsync vs $timeout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17301572/angularjs-evalasync-vs-timeout) .