# Child Elements missing in Directive

Tags: jquery, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have an defined a directive:

```
$(function () {
    angular.module(['myApp']).directive('rootSlider', function () {
        return {
            restrict: 'E',
            template: '<ul><li ng-repeat="item in items"><img ng-src="{{item.url}}" /></li></ul>',           
            scope: {
                items: '='
            },
            replace: true,
            compile: function ($templateElement, $templateAttributes) {
                return function ($scope, $element, $attrs) {

                    var $scope.items.length //expect 2, get 2
                    var numChildren $element.children().length //expect 2, get 0
                };
            }
        };
    });
});
```

Although the `$scope.items` property has 2 items, and in the final rendered DOM there are two `<li>` elements, in the link function `$element` does not yet have children.

At what point in the angular lifecycle can I get the completely rendered element (my intention is to use a jQuery slider plugin here).

The markup is

```
<root-slider items="ModelPropertyWithTwoItems"></root-slider>
```

UPDATE:

I was able to get this to work correctly with a combination of $watchCollection and $evalAsync.

```
$(function () {
    angular.module(['myApp']).directive('rootSlider', ['$timeout', function ($timeout) {
        return {
            restrict: 'E',
            template: '<ul class="bxslider"><li ng-repeat="item in items"><img ng-src="{{item.url}}" /></li></ul>',
            scope: {
                items: '='
            },
            compile: function ($templateElement, $templateAttributes) {
                return function ($scope, $element, $attrs) {
                    $scope.$watchCollection('items', function (newCollection, oldCollection) {
                        if ($scope.slider) {
                            $scope.$evalAsync(function () {
                                $scope.slider.reloadSlider();
                            });
                        }
                        else {

                            $scope.$evalAsync(function () {
                                $scope.slider = $element.find('.bxslider').bxSlider();
                            });
                        }

                    });

                };
            }
        };
    } ]);
});
```

Watch collection fires once on directive initialization (since it is a collection, you can't compare the newValue and oldValue, so I ended up adding the slider object to the $scope that gets created for the instance of the directive.

I use $evalAsync to defer execution of the jQuery code which (so far) is proving to avoid flicker on all browsers (it seems to run before $timeout(function(){}, 0).

The solution above could probably be simplified by just returning a link function (rather than a compile function, which turned out to be unneccessary).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A common way to wait for the DOM to finish rendering in Angular is to use `$timeout`.  Here's an [explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17301572/angularjs-evalasync-vs-timeout) of the various options and [here's another look at this](http://blog.brunoscopelliti.com/run-a-directive-after-the-dom-has-finished-rendering).

So this should resolve this for you.  Include `$timeout` in your directive:

```
angular.module(['myApp']).directive('rootSlider', function ($timeout) {
```

And then wrap your

```
$timeout(function() {
     var numChildren $element.children().length;
},0);
```

There has been a [request for a more official feature supporting this](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/1306) and here's Angular's own [Misko Hevery](https://github.com/mhevery)'s comment before he closed the issue:

> So that is a very complex question. The issue is that with
>   data-binding there is no clear start/end to the update cycle, it is
>   continues. I am sure that is not the answer you are looking for, but
>   angular is not like other frameworks, and so it lives by different
>   rules.
>
> How would you imagine this would work? What kind of and when should
>   you receive these notifications.

So far it looks like nobody has come up with a response to this question posted near the end by 3emad:

> I'm just curious about $timeout down side

I've taken it as encouraging for this approach that nobody has yet posted a downside.

Comment: This works, but it creates a situation where the unformatted  elements are displayed temporarily.  Seems like there would be a more framework specific hook for this.

Comment: $timeout is used pretty commonly for this- but I totally get that it seems kludgy. I'm puzzled that you're seeing a flash that you didn't before as this should not delay loading of the image/template. Is something else waiting on length? Here's a demo with a 2 second delay in the timeout, but the template loads normally: jsfiddle.net/csnGL/2

Comment: Marking this as the answer.  The $watch solution didn't specifically address the problem (although it was helpful), and link to the feature request you posted led me to $evalAsync.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You might want to use [`$watch`](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24rootScope.Scope#methods_%24watch) to catch up the change of model.

```
$scope.$watch('items', function(newValue) {
    // logic about items here...
}, true); // pass true since it should be an array
```

Comment: Thanks.  I had figured out something similar.  I will update the question shortly, but I now use $watchCollection, and when it fires on initialization children().length is 2 (as expected).  It still flickers on IE(9), but it looks like it works with other browsers.