# When using AngularJS's $timeout, what's the default delay?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, timeout

On the remarkably brief [AngularJS $timeout documentation page](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/%24timeout), the 'delay' argument is stated as optional.  When using $timeout without specifying a delay, I note that a delay is still applied.

Can anyone tell me how much time is allotted for the delay when the argument is left implicit?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When `$timeout` delay is omitted, it defaults to `0`. However, the block of code contained in it is executed after the DOM has been manipulated by Angular. See response to [AngularJS $evalAsync vs $timeout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17301572/angularjs-evalasync-vs-timeout)

Answer (score 7):

My understanding is that a delay of '0' means that it will be picked-up as part of the next run of the event loop.  That's an especially short but indeterminate amount of time.

Answer (score 2):

It's immediately executed, the default would be zero. Here is a jsfiddle showing it:
http://jsfiddle.net/dgarlitt/rqs3p/1/

```
angular
    .module('myApp',[])
        .controller('MyCtrl', function($scope, $timeout) {
            $timeout(function() {
                $scope.name = 'World';
            });
        });
```

Answer (score 2):

The default delay is 0. The documentation has been updated since.

[offical angularjs $timeout doc](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$timeout)