# ngRepeat in compiled by $compile does not work

Tags: angularjs

I need to dynamically compile html and pass it from function as text.
So, I have this code (simplified version for debugging purpose):

```
angular.module('app', [])
  .run(function($rootScope, $compile){
    var data = ["1","2"];
    var html  =
        '<div>' +
        '<ul>' +
        '<li ng-repeat="score in data">{{score}}</li>' +
        '</ul>'+
        '</div>';

    var el = angular.element(html);

    $rootScope.data = data;

    var result = $compile(el)($rootScope);

    console.log(result.html());
  })
```

The result is only:

```
<ul><!-- ngRepeat: score in data --></ul>
```

So, it looks like ngRepeat does not "repeat" "li" element.

Why?

JsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/yoorek/K4Cmk/

(I know DOM manipulation should be in directive etc. and I know how to do it other way but I need to understand why this does not work)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you look at the angular source code, ngRepeat will manipulate the DOM and "repeat" the elements within the $watchCollection handler:

[ngRepeat Link Function](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/directive/ngRepeat.js#L344)

When you manually compile and link the element from the run block, the $watch handlers for your element have been set up but the $digest phase has not happened yet.  It is the $digest phase where the scope examines all of the $watch expressions and executes their corresponding watch handlers.

If you want to inspect the element after the $digest (render) phase you can use $timeout:

```
  $timeout(function() {
       console.log(el.html());
      alert(el.html());
  });
```

[Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DUM7t/)

Comment: i have such issue right now, but it is a bit different.

i have my template which is from view :

var table = document.getElementById('my-table').outerHTML;

and i use templateCache :
$templateCache.put('template', table); then i compile this : 
var el = $compile($templateCache.get('template'))($rootScope);

still, it doesn't work for me. do you have any ideas?

Comment: when I run your code in " angular.module('app', [])
  .run ", it works but when i move it controller " angular.module('app', [])
  .controller "
i still get something like this <ul><!-- ngRepeat: score in data --></ul>

Answer (score 0):

I was wondering why the answer above does not work with $scope.$evalAsync() instead of $timeout. 
I believe these explain:
1. http://www.bennadel.com/blog/2605-scope-evalasync-vs-timeout-in-angularjs.htm
2. [AngularJS : $evalAsync vs $timeout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17301572/angularjs-evalasync-vs-timeout)