# $compile and ng-repeat not returning correct element

Tags: javascript, angularjs, compilation, angularjs-ng-repeat

I can't get `$compile` to work manually with `ng-repeat`. There is a similar question here: [ngRepeat in compiled by $compile does not work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24638351/ngrepeat-in-compiled-by-compile-does-not-work), but it doesn't resolve the issue here, as I manually call `$digest` on the scope yet it still doesn't work.

The code I am referring to is here:

**js**:

```
angular.module('myApp', []);

angular.module('myApp').directive('test', ['$compile', '$rootScope', '$timeout', 
    function ($compile, $rootScope, $timeout) {
        var myScope = $rootScope.$new();
        myScope.numbers = [1, 2, 3];

        var html = '<div ng-repeat="number in numbers">{{ number }}</div>';
        var html2 = '<div>{{ numbers }}</div>';

        var returnObject = $compile(html)(myScope);
        $timeout(function () {
            myScope.$digest();
            console.log(returnObject);
        });

        return {};
    }
]);
```

**html**:

```
<html ng-app="myApp">

    <head>
    ...
    </head>

    <body>
        <h1 test>Hello Plunker!</h1>
    </body>

</html>
```

**link to plunker**: http://plnkr.co/edit/RC1EILu16GPr0MGmSpcb?p=preview

If you switch the `html` variable to `html2` it will interpolate and return the object as expected. But in it's current state, I expect to get a collection of DIVs with 1, 2, 3 ...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Internally, ng-repeat works by adding elements to the parent element of the directive ng-repeat is called on.  Your compiled ng-repeat has no parent to add it's elements to, so it can't work.

Add a parent div ([Plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/e1pfgUsjivnmzMGjWUCj?p=preview))

```
var html = '<div><div ng-repeat="number in numbers">{{ number }}</div></div>';
var html2 = '<div>{{ numbers }}</div>';
var returnObject = $compile(html)(myScope);
    $timeout(function () {
        myScope.$digest();
      console.log(returnObject.children());
```