# AngularJS: Cannot get innerHTML of dynamic element within a directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am trying to get the `innerHTML` of an **element with dynamic content** form within a **directive**.

Below is the *Plunker*:

https://plnkr.co/edit/rXVin1LPWzpH4eMqZc7R?p=preview

The one in **green** is the expected result.
The one in **red** is the part I hope to get working.

Notice on the `console.log` result, the outcome for `el.innerHTML` is `{{ item }}`. Why isn't it getting the text that is bound to it? How do I get it to work?

Comment: Try add setTimeout into the directive.

Comment: Thanks, @digit! That's one way of doing it. https://plnkr.co/edit/8vGmylxVOUerWctZOF7q?p=preview

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's because Angular hasn't finished processing the child templates from `ng-repeat`.

You can warp the code in `scope.$evalAsync` to make it work:

```
link: function(scope, element, attr, content) {

  scope.$evalAsync(function() {

    var el = element[0];

    // Code
  });
}
```

More on `$evalAsync` vs `$timeout`: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17303759/2887841

Comment: Thanks. Works great!