# How update view in Angular(avoid $apply already in progress)?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to show button(Some Button) while some logic is doing in my app, and then hide this button.

By clicking Some Button I call expand() where set data.loading to true, at this point I want to button appears, when I set data.loading to false I want to button hides, but view is not updates.

```
<button ng-show="data.loading">Some Button</button>
<button ng-click="expand(data)">Other Button</button>
```

Function:

```
$scope.expand = function (data) {
    data.loading = true;
    // Some Button must be visible now
    // Some logic here;
    data.loading = false;
    // Some Button must be invisible now
}
```

$scope.$apply() -  returns error: $apply already in progress

$scope.safeApply() - doesn't throw exception, but doesn't updates view.

$timeout - doesn't updates view.

Comment: What is the `//logic here` part - you also have `nng-click` in your view.

Comment: @tymeJV //logic here is call to api, nng-click it's typo, fixed

Comment: Please post that logic - it's probably the cause of the whole problem...

Comment: put `data.loading` in $scope as Sreehari S answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Referencing your data model via `$scope` attribute along with moving your main logic out of current digest cycle (with [`$timeout` or `$evalAsync`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17301572/angularjs-evalasync-vs-timeout)) should fix the “$apply already in progress” message in your case:

```
$scope.expand = function () {
   $scope.data.loading = true;
   $timeout(function () {
       // Some logic here;
       $scope.data.loading = false;
   });
};
```

I usually prefer to (1) hold loading progress inside a service, and (2) use promises to manage progress status. In the example below, `logicFunction()` returns a promise.

```
$scope.expand = function () {
    progressStatusService.started("Loading something…")
    logicFunction().finally(function () {
        progressStatusService.finished("Loading something…")
    });
};
// progressStatusService implementation left as a challenge to the reader
```

Global progress service is mostly intended for app-wide loading indication—if loading status only affects one specific widget, then it might be an overhead.

However, the deferred/promises approach could be generally useful and easier to read (see more docs at [`$q`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q)).

Answer (score 1):

```
$scope.expand = function () {
   $scope.data.loading = true;
   // Some Button must be visible now
   // Some logic here;
   $scope.data.loading = false;
   // Some Button must be invisible now
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `$scope.data.loading` as suggested by @Sreehari and use `ng-if` in you view instead of `ng-show`.